# How to copy existing app logs to TestFlight and using macros

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nslog, testflight

I am currently integrating the test flight SDK.  Currently I have a macro for logging called DebugLog:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DebugLog(s,...) NSLog(@"Thread:%@  [%@ %@] %@", [[NSThread currentThread] name], NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [NSString stringWithFormat:s,##__VA_ARGS__])
#else
    #define DebugLog(s,...)
#endif
```

I now want to integrate Testflight's TFLog into our project:

```
#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

My question is, is there a way of redirecting the logging from DebugLog to TFLog i.e. DebugLog fires and logs to the console and it also logs to TFLog?

Comment: Do you want `DebugLog` calls `TFLog` ?

Comment: I just want to make sure that all the logs made by DebugLog are also made to TFLog

Comment: Yeah I have tried nothing is coming through though - I obviously removed the if statement as the app running in test flight won't be in debug mode at all

Comment: Can you give me the definition of `TFLog`?

Comment: void TFLog(NSString *format, ...);
    void TFLogv(NSString *format, va_list arg_list);

Comment: I have downloaded sdk please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one

```
//Here I have added NSLog followed by TFLog
#define DebugLog(s,...) NSLog(@"Thread:%@  [%@ %@] %@", [[NSThread currentThread] name], NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [NSString stringWithFormat:s,##__VA_ARGS__]);TFLog(s,##__VA_ARGS__)
//You can use this within  #ifdef #endif construct
```